# Как добавить toolbar во Fragment, который использует DataBinding?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

У меня есть фрагмент с `RecyclerView`, вот его xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@color/background_color">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
</layout>
```

Так вот я пытаюсь добавить сюда `Toolbar`, но не получается. Пишет, что нельзя иметь более одного элемента внутри тега `<layout>`.

Так вот как его добавить ?
Или нужно добавить его в активити-хост ?

И еще чем отличается `Toolbar`, который добавляется вместе с темой приложения. Например: `Theme.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar`, от Toolbar, который добавляется в xml разметку ?

Comment: разница есть в том,  как используется `Toolbar`. Он может быть либо эмуляцией ActionBar (через метод setSupportActionBar() ) и тогда выполнять роль системного бара (иконка назад/гамбургер, заголовок , меню приложения и пр.), либо это просто View, которое вы можете наполнять по своему усмотрению, например поиск со строкой ввода. В темах, оканчивающихся на *.ActionBar* используется, собственно, системный `ActionBar`, который к виджету `Toolbar` не имеет отношения.

Comment: Обычно нужно выбрать, будете ли вы использовать системный ActionBar применив соответствующую тему, оканчивающуюся на *.ActionBar*, либо же использовать в его роли `Toolbar`, подключенный по первому варианту коммента выше. Такой вариант дает более гибкую настройку, если она требуется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Можешь использовать внутри `<layout>` любую реализацию `ViewGroup`, например `<LinearLayout>` с горизонтальной ориентацией.

---

2. При использовании темы `Theme.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar` будет использован стандартный `ActionBar`. Если нужны дополнительные методы для его кастомизации то можно добавить программно `Toolbar` (это `ActionBar` на стеройдах).